# A good log file analyzer for windows

Tags: text-editors, logging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Log viewer on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/153/log-viewer-on-windows)

Is there a text-editor for windows that can open for me first n lines of a large file? It would be nice if it could also open a set of lines from the middle of the file.

EDIT: Basically my requirement is that I want to analyze huge(>2GB) log files. So any good tool that can open huge files with some analysis capabilities(searching, text highlighting etc.) would be nice. I like notepad++ but it wouldn't open a file even of about 650 MB.

P.S. - Open source tools will be preferred.

Answer (score 2):

[This thread on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/1602/good-text-editors-or-viewers-for-large-log-files) should help you out.

Comment: The link is outdated :(

Answer (score 1):

[BareTail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/) might be of interest. On Unix you can use the [tail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_(Unix)) command.