# log viewer on Windows, roughly equivalant to Linux's Log viewer or OSX's Console?

Tags: windows, logging, administration

Are there any good log viewers on Windows roughly equivalent to Linux's log viewer or OS X's Console?

[image]

[image]

I need to be able to tail multiple logs, with search & filtering.

I've seen BareTail as mentioned in the ["Log viewer on Windows" question](https://superuser.com/questions/153/log-viewer-on-windows), but I am looking for other candidates.

Comment: This question is *not* a duplicate.  I am not looking for just any log viewer, I'm looking for equivalents to other software on OSX and Linux.

Comment: So The answer was that there isn't an equivalent that I found.

Comment: We ended up using splunk anyway to aggregate all that data.

Comment: https://github.com/Kittyfisto/Tailviewer I just downloaded and it's pretty awesome so far and free!  my only wish is they add dark theme

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it will do exactly what you want but look at [PsLogList](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897544.aspx) from sysinternals.

Answer (score 1):

[LogViewerPro](http://www.uvviewsoft.com/logviewer/) looks promising.  If you were only interested in the Windows event logs, I would suggest [MyEventViewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/my_event_viewer.html).  But you're not, so I won't.