# Windows log tail viewer

Tags: windows, logging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Log viewer on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/153/log-viewer-on-windows)

Does anyone know a good log tail viewer for Windows?

Comment: Do you want to monitor the Windows event logs or view the tail of a log (text) file?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/221756/how-to-use-tail-exe-windows-2003-resource-kit-tool

Answer (score 2):

There is a port of tail to windows called [Tail for Win32](http://tailforwin32.sourceforge.net/) which I haven't used, but I have used
[BareTail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/) quite a bit for log monitoring and it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

Going in to Event Viewer and sort via the date column?

As for command prompt, you do not say what version of Windows you are using. Since Windows Server 2003, you have the script `eventquery.vbs` which you can script against, but this is only on the server editions.

If you can run Powershell, there is a nice commandlet you can run called `get-winevent`.

I hope this helps, but I am not really sure of any other built in tools that can do this.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [BareTail and BareTailPro](http://baremetalsoft.com/baretailpro/index.php) by Bare Metal Soft.  You can highlight lines that contain certain strings and it is very quick to get going.

You can also use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), a Linux-style commmand prompt tool, which has tail built in.