# How to use tail.exe : Windows 2003 Resource kit tool

Tags: windows, tail

Tail.exe from Windows 2003 Resource kit [link to download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&DisplayLang=en)

I tried "option -f *filename.xyz*"  - this doesnot seem to update. 
In my .net app, log file is updated using this code :

```
FileStream fileStream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write; ...
```

*throws access exception, file in use by another tool* which is Tail.exe

Am I missing something here.. how should tail.exe be used.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a different `tail` port? E.g. the one included in [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) which has worked for me with a log file opened in a similar manner.

These days I tend to prefer the follow functionality in `less` (press shift-F to follow when viewing a file) because I can switch out of follow to look back in the file.

Comment: I chked other similar questions that suggest this tool and other tail tools. But my company doesnot allows installing them :(

Comment: @Avinash understanding the policy might help you get an exception. Just remember to work *with* your bosses and make an economic argument (this tool will save time, which is worth $$....).

Answer (score 0):

You could try ["Unix tail equivalent command in Windows Powershell"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426442/unix-tail-equivalent-command-in-windows-powershell).
The nice thing about this solution is that there is no extra software to install provided that PowerShell is alreayd installed.  Also, it may be more acceptable for your company to allow PS to be installed if is not already.  It ships with Windows Vista and newer and is available for Windows XP via Windows Update.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 6.9.2, Notepad++ can replicate tail functionality by monitoring an open file.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using unixutils tail for over 15 years and recently found some odd issues with it and decided to find an alternative. After digging around all solutions that provide a CLI only tool that works on modern windows, the only one was Cygwin. After some testing I realized you can just pull out the tail.exe from cygwin and the required DLL's and they work on their own.

To simplify this for others, I've created a GitHub Project called [cygtail](https://github.com/JavaScriptDude/cygtail) that contains all the necessary files to use this tail version. I've also included checksums and Virus Total permalinks for reference and validation. Please refer to the [cygtail](https://github.com/JavaScriptDude/cygtail) project for installation and usage instructions.

And if you like, please give me a star ;)

Answer (score -1):

I landed here after downloading the Windows 2003 Resource Kit Tool and searching how to use tail, specifically I wanted to watch an output file during a build.

`tail output.txt -f`

`-f` will follow and append the file content.

Comment: Why the downvote...? I landed here after searching "how to use tail windows 2003 resource kit tool" and this question title is an exact match - "How to use tail.exe : Windows 2003 Resource kit tool". None of the answers here actually answer the question, they say to use another application. My answer exactly describes how to use tail, answers the exact question I asked, and answers the title of this question precisely so if someone else lands here they will have their answer.